# How to look for phone numbers in a string of text

Tags: python, regex, expression

Here is what I have so far:

```
import re
text = "If you want to call me, my old number was 905-343-2112 and it has 
been changed to 289-544-2345"
phone = re.findall(r'((\d{3})-(\d{3})-(\d{4}))', text)
for call in phone:
    print (call[0])
```

I am guessing my regular expression for finding the phone number isnt great because if I take out the square brackets when printing call, it seems to give me the whole number and then it breaks down each set of numbers.  How could I polish this code

Comment: If you just want the entire phone number, and not the individual segments of it, then get rid of all those parentheses in the regex - they are defining capturing groups that you don't need.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A comprehensive regex for phone number validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123559/a-comprehensive-regex-for-phone-number-validation)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use non-capturing group for segments of the phone number:

```
phone = re.findall(r'((?:\d{3})-(?:\d{3})-(?:\d{4}))', text)
                       ^^        ^^        ^^
```

Or better yet, just drop the parentheses

```
phone = re.findall(r'\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}', text)
```

Answer (score 3):

You're close but you don't need the parentheses in the pattern:

```
phone = re.findall(r'\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}', text)
print(phone)
# ['905-343-2112', '289-544-2345']
```